# Drawing a complete graph of equally-spaced points on a circle's circumference with Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm writing a function that dots equally-spaced points on the circumference of a circle centered at origin, then draws lines between all points.

I have been messing with this code for a while now and I can not seem to get it to function as intended. I need to make a circle out of points from the given radius and number of points in turtle. This is what I have so far:

```
from turtle import *

def drawLineSeg (p, q):
    up()
    goto(p)
    down()
    goto(q)

def pntCirc (r, n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        up()
        goto(0,0)
        forward(r)
        down()
        dot(10)
        L.append (pos())
        right(360/n)

L = []

def clique (r, n):
    pntCirc (r, n)
    color ('blue')
    for i in range(0, len(L)):
        drawLineSeg (L[0], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[1], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[2], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[3], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[4], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[5], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[6], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[7], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[8], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[9], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[10], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[11], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[12], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[13], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[14], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[15], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[16], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[17], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[18], L[i])
        drawLineSeg (L[19], L[i])
    return

speed(50)
color ('red')
clique (300, 20)
# clique (300, 8)
# clique (300, 16) 
hideturtle()
done()
```

In the clique function, I have tried using `for` loops and while loops, which is around what I need to use for this to work; I can't use any more technical stuff like `enumerate`, `numpy`, or `matplotlib`. I need to make this work for any amount of given points, not just the 20 points I tested for. It throws an `IndexError` when I test for 8 points, for example. How do I do this with one code, not hard-written?

```
clique (300, 20)
# clique (300, 8)
# clique (300, 16)
```

I have, as stated above, hard coded it to give me the full result ([this is the full model that I hard coded the function for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98F71.png)) when using 20 points, but if I just put in:

```
for i in range(0, len(L)):
        drawLineSeg (L[0], L[i])
```

[I get this instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Kchu.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am currently stuck and am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You'll need an inner loop--for each point, for each other point in the remainder of the list, draw a line between them. You're pretty close here.

Answer (score 4):

Great effort here. What you're drawing is a [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph). You're very close, only missing an inner loop which is essentially what the hardcoded 20 calls simulates.

We need to find all combinations of points, so the logic is essentially a nested loop:

```
for each point at index i from 0 to length(points):
    for each other point from index i + 1 to length(points):
        draw a line between the two points
```

While moving the turtle from the center will work, I'd prefer to compute the points around the circumference of the circle mathematically. The formula for a point is:

```
x = math.cos(angle_in_radians) * radius + center_x
y = math.sin(angle_in_radians) * radius + center_y
```

... but the center is assumed to be 0 for our purposes (this is a good thing to make a parameter).

To compute all of the points around the circumference, we can iterate from 0 to 360 degrees in increments of 360 / n (the number of points we want to draw), then convert our angle to radians and plug into the formula. No lists required.

As a cosmetic aside, I'd prefer to avoid `from turtle import *` which brings in too many functions into the namespace. Better to `import turtle`, then use the `turtle` prefix going forward. I'd also prefer to create a `Turtle` instance and pass it into the function so it's not reliant on global state.

I'd also prefer to use parameters on the function for all of the available knobs. Center `x` and `y` would be nice to add.

The final result is:

```
import math
import turtle

def clique(t, r, n, dotsize=10, dotcolor="red", linecolor="blue"):
    for i in range(n):
        a = 360 / n * i
        x = math.cos(math.radians(a)) * r
        y = math.sin(math.radians(a)) * r
        t.color(linecolor)

        for i in range(i + 1, n):
            a = 360 / n * i
            xx = math.cos(math.radians(a)) * r
            yy = math.sin(math.radians(a)) * r
            t.goto(x, y)
            t.pendown()
            t.goto(xx, yy)
            t.penup()

        t.goto(x, y)
        t.color(dotcolor)
        t.dot(dotsize)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.penup()
    t.speed("fastest")
    clique(t, 200, 7)
    turtle.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate @ggorlen's circle math approach to a solution (+1), but I think the shortest path from where you are to where you want to be is via a nested loop that draws lines from every point to every other point avoiding null lines (same point) and redundant lines:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def drawLineSeg(p, q):
    turtle.goto(p)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(q)
    turtle.penup()

def pntCirc(r, n):
    for _ in range(1, n + 1):
        turtle.forward(r)
        turtle.dot(10)

        positions.append(turtle.position())

        turtle.backward(r)
        turtle.right(360 / n)

def clique(r, n):
    pntCirc(r, n)

    turtle.color('blue')

    for start in range(len(positions) - 1):
        for end in range(start + 1, len(positions)):
            drawLineSeg(positions[start], positions[end])

positions = []

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.color('red')
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()

clique(300, 20)

screen.exitonclick()
```